# Use WebApi controller as default instead of MVC vontroller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a webapi project and I don't want to return any html or razor views. I want the default controller and action to be an HTTP GET for one of my API controllers. My code is the following:

MVC route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Enpoint", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
        );
    }
}
```

WebApi route config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiDefault",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Application_Start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Do you know how can I configure the router to redirect to by default:

```
GET /api/home
```

Comment: Hi, but remember, web api is about to build http services, not about any client (view, file, etc), your client needs to call the resource and next do something with the data, so the concept of "default" is not present here!